# HashMap "Unique" Keys

Tags: java

Firstly, I'd like to say I am still learning java, so excuse any unconventional code and/or questions.

I'm trying to allow the HashMap to set 'unique' keys while only using one put method.

This is what I currently have:

```
static int killcount = 0; 

static Map<Integer, Integer> enumMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public static void incrementKillcount() {
    enumMap.put(getId(), killcount++);  
}
```

(Again, excuse any unconventional java code, I'm still learning).

In this instance, if I'm not mistaken, the key is interchangeable (or at least from my experimenting). So the key doesn't really matter all that much. But while only having one put method, every key shares the same value. I'd like to make the value have some sort of 'unique' value.

For example, if I wanted this to count by increasing the killcount by 1 (killcount++;) until it reached 10, and then moving to a different key to count to 10 again, it would start counting from 10 instead of 1.

Thanks in advance, and again, excuse me for my terrible java skills! :)

Comment: what does `getId()` do?

Comment: the key is interchangeable with what? value? another key?

Comment: Why not turn the `key` and `value` around? or is the current `key` also unique? For the key is, by definition, unique

Comment: It doenst look like you would need a HashMap here. Can you explain why you are using one?

Comment: @sharonbn it's completely for example purposes.

Comment: key matters a lot,through the key you will get your element. each unique key will be having its associated value.

Comment: @the key, in this instance, would be interchanged with another key.

Comment: is getId() method always returning same int value ?

Comment: ok, but I dont understand the question. you want to have 10 kill counts  for one key and then other 10 counts for a diff key?

Comment: @BadK Unfortunately, it's a little hard to explain what I'm trying to get at. But everything I said in this post was being used as an example. Do you have any other ideas besides a HashMap?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Even an example should have a goal.

Comment: @sharonbn Yes, precisely. I'd like to restart the value at 1 for every key.

Comment: @PiyushMittal I see, that's a good point. Any means to generate a unique key while only using one put method?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Mostly learning purposes, just thought about this earlier today.

Comment: @andrewDev15 OK, but what should your code do? Let's say I know how to implement Quicksort in Python, and now I want to learn how to do it in Java. Then my Java code will be of learning purpose, but it should do the Quicksort algorithm. It is not clear to me, what your code is intended to do.

Comment: Key- Value- Key Value - ?? You are talking about `Map`, be precise about your wording. Voting to close as it is unclear to answer.

Comment: @andrewDev15 see the answer

Comment: I also think this is too unclear... I really did try to understand and failed

Comment: Can close, although I agree it is unclear, I think I may have gotten some answers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is static key word for killcount in your:-

```
static int killcount = 0;
```

The killcount will be initialized only once since it is static.
So increment operator will increment the previous value in killcount.

> Solution to your problem

:-
set the killcount to zero while changing the key after saving it to map i.e. once killcount reaches 10.

```
public static void incrementKillcount() {   
        enumMap.put(getId(), killcount++); 
        if(killcount==10){
            //resetting the static killcount value once it reaches 10
            killcount=0;
        }
```

For Scenario in your comment:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int sizeOfEachJar=10;
    int numberOfJars=2;
    Map<Integer, Integer> jarMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(sizeOfEachJar);
    //I am putting 10 cookies in each jar which is max size of each jar
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfJars;i++){
    jarMap.put(i, sizeOfEachJar);
    }
    //Now eating three cookies from first jar
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        jarMap.put(1, sizeOfEachJar--); 
    }
    //Now eating 2 cookies out of 2nd jar
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        jarMap.put(2, sizeOfEachJar--); 
    }

    //Now finding out how many cookies remaining in all jars
    int remainingCookies=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfJars;i++){
        remainingCookies+=jarMap.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(remainingCookies);
}
```

Comment: Ok this is sort of what I'm looking for, I've already tried this though. I want this data to be saved once it reaches 10. For a better analogy, let's say there was 5 cookie jars (lol), each have 10 cookies in them. Let's say I eat some out of all them. Let's say I ate 3 cookies out of jar 1 and 2 cookies out of jar 2, I'd like variables to be able to tell how much cookies I ate out of what jar. It's extremely hard what I'm trying to say haha I've been trying my best.

Comment: Check my edit in answer. Try to replicate your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your getID() code whether it returns same value or not.

Answer (score 0):

as per your words your getId is returning same value each time
assuming `same =1`

```
int getId()
{
return same;
}
```

update your code with `getId()` by placing some use full logic to return a `key`

you may update like:

```
int getId()
{
return same++;
}
```

you may take same as static or according to your convince.
prefer **effective java** for the same.

Comment: His problem is  "it would start counting from 10 instead of 1" with the value  and not with the key.

Comment: i posted the answer before your edit :// @andrewDev15